# Conteúdo dinâmico em duas colunas

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

Ola,

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em php aonde iremos gerar um arquivo pdf, onde cada página será dividade em duas colunas.

O conteúdo do PDF será adicionado dinamicamente através de um gerenciador de conteúdos.

O desafio é: exibir esse conteúdo na página de maneira onde o texto preencha o primeiro lado, após o segundo e assim por diante.

Como se fosse um documento do word dividido em duas colunas por página.

[image: Pequena ilustração]

Não sei por onde começar, o processo de adicionar e gerar o PDF é tranquilo.

Como fazer esse processo.

Obrigado desde-já pelo auxilio.

Comment: Como você está gerando esse pdf (está usando alguma biblioteca para isso)?

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, seu layout já tem 2 colunas, ou vc quer dividir o conteúdo em duas colunas só na hora da impressão? Como vc pretende controlar essa quebra do conteúdo, até onde fica em uma coluna e o que vai para a outra coluna?

Comment: Vou dividir em duas colunas somente na hora da impressão.
Essa forma de quebrar o conteúdo das colunas que não sei como fazer.